# Python ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm facing a huge encoding problem in Python when dealing with ISO-8859-1 / Latin-1 character set.

When using `os.listdir` to get the contents of a folder I'm getting the strings encoded in ISO-8859-1 (ex: ''Ol\xe1 Mundo''), however in the Python interpreter the same string is encoded to a different charset:

```
In : 'Olá Mundo'.decode('latin-1')
Out: u'Ol\xa0 Mundo'
```

How can I force Python to decode the string to the same format?. I've seen that `os.listdir` is returning the strings correctly encoded but the interpreter is not ('á' character corresponds to '\xe1' in ISO-8859-1, not to '\xa0'):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Any thoughts on how to overcome ?

Comment: To be a bit pedantic: `os.listdir()` returns bytes. The process that named the file chose to give the file a name with a specific interpretation in iso-8859-1. Filenames could just as easily be stored in BIG-5 or JIS, and `os.listdir()` wouldn't care.

Comment: @sarnold: `os.listdir()` can return strings or bytes: it depends upon what you pass in, and on the contents of the directory.

Answer (score 3):

When you enter a non-unicode string literal in a python2 interactive session, the system default encoding will be assumed for it.

It appears that you are using windows, and that the default encoding is therefore probably "cp850" or "cp437":

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'cp850'
>>> 'Olá Mundo'
'Ol\xa0 Mundo'
>>> u'Olá Mundo'.encode('cp850')
'Ol\xa0 Mundo'
```

If you change the code-page to 1252 (which is roughly equivalent to latin1), the strings will display as expected:

```
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'cp1252'
>>> 'Olá Mundo'
'Ol\xe1 Mundo'
```